# mysql-slow-log file is not generated

Tags: mysql, logging, mysql-slow-query-log

```
log_slow_queries  = "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\mysql-slow.log" 
long_query_time  = 1
```

I wrote the lines above in my.ini file. But after running my query, which is taking more than 1 second to execute, the log file is not generated. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Don't know about lesser operating systems, but on Linux and Unix, it will only append to a file which already exists - it won't create the file if it's not already there - try creating the file first then restart mysqld.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please `restart mysql service`.
Pl execute this and check : `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%slow_query_log%';` this will help you to identify the location of the mysql slow query log file.

Comment: can u tell me the process how to create it

Comment: did u try restarting the mysql service after making changes in your my.cnf file. that does help sometimes.

Comment: Can you refer this http://www.mydigitallife.info/enable-logging-of-slow-queries-slow-query-log-in-mysql-database/? In case the path is wrong then mysql will write in data directory also.